# Trouble building a haskell module in IntelliJ

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea

I get the following error message when I try to build a package in intellJIDEA using the haskell plugin.  I think this message is an error with `buildwrapper` and not the plugin.  However I am not sure how to synchronize buildwrapper in windows.

```
Error:(2, 8) ghc: Could not find module `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec'
    It is a member of the hidden package `parsec-3.1.5'.
    Perhaps you need to add `parsec' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    It is a member of the hidden package `parsec-3.1.3'.
    Perhaps you need to add `parsec' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had no idea intellij had a haskell plugin...

Comment: I tried the plugin a while ago and whilst it gave context sensitive highlighting (keywords and so forth), I couldn't get any other functions to work. It would be nice to run haskell programs thru IntelliJ but I had to resort to alt-tab and run them externally... which is a pity...

Comment: Perhaps you need to add `parsec' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.

Comment: @jberryman Giving spitredd the benefit of the doubt, I suspect that much is known but how to do that within his IDE is not.

Comment: I had to manually add parsec to the build-depends file, something I was hoping that IDE would do.

Answer (score 1):

Manually edit the `build-depends` file to add the missing package.

Comment: Please provide more substance to your answer.